# How to do proper exception handling when developing a library in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exception

Let's say I want to create DLL library that would provide common file system services in an easy to use way. This library can then be used in 3rd party .NET applications.
Let's say the this library provides only this interface to the public:

```cs
public interface IFileSystemService
{
    void CreateDirectory(string path);
    void DeleteDirectory(string path);
    bool DirectoryExists(string path);
    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string path);
    void DeleteFile(string path);
    bool FileExists(string path);
    void CopyFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, bool overwriteExisting);
    // ... and other methods   
}
```

What would be best practices for exception handling when it comes to implementing this interface by using standard .NET classes from [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO(v=vs.110).aspx) namespaces (eg. [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx), [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) etc...)? 
How can I make this library robust and easy for use by the client code? How can I make this so that client code for error handling is clean and not overly complex?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem

Comment: What IS clear and not complex error handling?

Comment: @reniuz: I expected that comment... Not sure really and I can't give exact definition andI hope that there is some consensus on that in the community. Eg. for me one thing would be writing client code with small number of try/catch blocks... maybe try blocks with not more than one or two catch blocks... Too many try/catchs clutter the code. Eg. when I do CopyFile() I'd like to have only one type of exception thrown with more details in InnerException maybe. Not sure if this is the right approach but that's what it means for me currently.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is do what you can to recover from the exception, but if you can't do anything let the exception propagate up to the caller and let them deal with it.

As how to make the library robust and easy to use, document as much as you possibly can for your library. You can use XML-Doc to include what exceptions get thrown right in the metadata for your DLL

(comments taken from `Directory.CreateDirectory(string)`)

```
public interface IFileSystemService
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates all directories and subdirectories as specified by <paramref name="path"/>.    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.IO.DirectoryInfo"/> as specified by <paramref name="path"/>.    /// 
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="path">The directory path to create.</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.IO.IOException">The directory specified by <paramref name="path"/> is read-only.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.UnauthorizedAccessException">The caller does not have the required permission.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException"><paramref name="path"/> is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters as defined by <see cref="F:System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars"/>.
    /// 
    /// -or-
    /// <paramref name="path"/> is prefixed with, or contains only a colon character (:).</exception>
    ///<exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="path"/> is null.</exception>
    ///<exception cref="T:System.IO.PathTooLongException">The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length. For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less than 248 characters and file names must be less than 260 characters.</exception>
    ///<exception cref="T:System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException">The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).</exception>
    ///<exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException"><paramref name="path"/> contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label ("C:\").</exception>
    void CreateDirectory(string path);

    //Do similar comments for the rest.
    void DeleteDirectory(string path);
    bool DirectoryExists(string path);
    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string path);
    void DeleteFile(string path);
    bool FileExists(string path);
    void CopyFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, bool overwriteExisting);
    // ... and other methods   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ***What would be best practices for exception handling when it comes to implementing this interface by using standard .NET classes from System.IO namespaces (eg. FileInfo, DirectoryInfo, Directory, File etc...)?***

The best practice as far as I'm concerned is to let the exceptions bubbling up. As a "framework" implementer, you can't know what will be the intention is exception handling for the user of your API. And because you don't know this user's intentions, it is preferable to let the exception be thrown.

1. By letting the exception bubbling up, you allow one to get the full stack trace of where the exception actually occured
2. You also allow one to handle the exceptions one wants to catch based on one context

Based on an [**Eric Lippert**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s blog post, [**Vexing Exceptions**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) which I can no longer find, I remember him saying it is best to see code like:

```
if (condition) throw new Exception("message");
```

than seeing:

```
try { something(); }
catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(); }
```

Because the stack trace is to be resetted each time an exception is rethrown. Or else, you may do:

```
try { something(); }
catch (Exception ex) { 
    handleTheExceptionInternallyForYourPurpose();
    throw ex; // simply let the exception flow go its way to the top, to the caller.
}
```

Plus, it all depends on what are your behaviour expectations. Let's say you don't want to allow null values as the `path` parameter, then you might want to throw an `ArgumentNullException` when it's the case.

```
public void CreateDirectory(string path) {
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) throw new ArgumentException("path");

    // create your directory here based on the path provided...
}
```

> ***How can I make this library robust and easy for use by the client code?***

My bet is you can't program for other programmers. You may have the best library ever in the world, one with less experience or not respecting the [**SRP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) might end up with messy code. It belongs to each programmer to follow some guidelines and respect the best practices and principles. Sadly enough, those principles are seldomly followed, at least in my corner of the world. Whatever you may do, there will almost always be a better way to do things depending on your context.

> ***How can I make this so that client code for error handling is clean and not overly complex?***

Complex stuff will always be complex to code, so there's no way to escape. By sticking with the [**SOLID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles, and use tomorrow's best practices, you shall have an easy and understandable library.

[**XML Comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b2s063f7(v=vs.100).aspx) are also a good way to go when it comes to libraries so that IntelliSense may display it while typing.